# Decomposing image (red channel)

Tags: scripts, gimp

I am working in opencv. right now I have a task to decompose images into only red channel. I can make it by using GIMP.
It goes like this:

Colors -> Components -> Decompose  (color model RGB)

This way I get 3 new grayscale images, one with green channel, one with red and one with blue channel.
I only need grayscale image with red channel. Anyways, problem is I have few thousand pictures in my folder named "positives" to convert, so if I do it this way it would take so much time.

Is there any way to write a script and run it from terminal to convert images into red channel and save them all in folder at once?

I guess it doesn't even  need to be a long script, it is probably a semi-simple command.

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO this stretches the definition of "questions about Ubuntu" - have you tried something like [Splitting Image using OpenCV in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181485/splitting-image-using-opencv-in-python) or [how do I separate the channels of an RGB image and save each one, using the 2.4.9 version of OpenCV?](http://answers.opencv.org/question/59529/how-do-i-separate-the-channels-of-an-rgb-image-and-save-each-one-using-the-249-version-of-opencv/)

Comment: Are you sure? I mean it's not about opencv. its about making some kind of  script/command that converts images in UBUNTU via terminal. Look at the answer bellow from Takkat. Anyways doesn't matter now it's solved. Thank you also for your ideas, I appreciate it!

Comment: Apologies - I took your opening statement *"I am working in opencv"* to indicate that you wanted an opencv solution to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need processing of many files we may want to use [ImageMagick](https://packages.ubuntu.com/imagemagick) command line tools [convert](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) or [mogrify](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php):

```
convert input.png -channel R -separate output.png
```

`R` is for red channel. Imagemagick also works on multiple files using wildcards or other [channels](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#channel) (`G`,`B` ...).

The following command is for many files that would not fit into the RAM. 
It will overwrite all existing image files in the current directory with a red channel greyscale. **[Do not work on originals!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935498/decomposing-image-red-channel)**

```
mogrify * -channel R -separate *
```

Comment: Takkat you're the boss! Thank you very much, works like charm :D